# How safe are online private key and seed generators?

Tags: myetherwallet, user-safety

Recent news from [IOTA wallets](https://www.ccn.com/a-number-of-iota-wallets-emptied-by-hackers-due-to-online-seed-generators/):

> Just two days ago, many users reported having their funds (an estimated $4 million) in their IOTA wallets stolen from an unknown source. The cause? Online seed generators.

Please, explain me, how to understand that there is enough randomness in online private key/seed generator? Is it safe to use [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/) or [Ian Coleman's Mnemonic Code Converter](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for the code converter, but MyEtherWallet can be run entirely offline and is open source, if there were a vulnerability it would almost certainly already have been exposed by now.

Comment: Mnemonic Code Converter can also be run offline: https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39 :-)

Comment: The ability to run website in offline mode does not say anything about the quality of the seed generator. As I understand it, they rely on a RNG in the browser. Isn't that as risky as using IOTA online seed generators?

Comment: We have a writeup on how we get entropy here https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/best-of/how-myetherwallet-gets-entropy-when-generating-wallets.html